# Wordpress: how to get plugin's folders permission

Tags: wordpress

**SOLVED**: plugin_dir_path(--FILE--).'MyFolder';

I have built a wordpress plugin (wp-content/plugins/MyPlugin) and I would to check some folders permission inside the MyPlugin directory.

My problem is that I don't what Wordpress constant or what PHP function I should use to target on of these directories.

```
if( !is_writable(WP_PLUGIN_URL.'MyFolder') )
{
    echo 'NOK'.'<hr>';  
}
```

This piece of code always returns 'NOK' whereas I am 100% sure 'MyFolder' is actually writable
.

Can you give me some piece of advice here to get the right file in order to target any folder that would be in my plugin directory?

thanks